# How to post JSON object to server using casper.open()?

Tags: json, curl, phantomjs, httprequest, casperjs

I'm trying to POST request to server using the following

```
this.open('someurl',{
            method: 'post',
            data:   {
                'memberId': obj.id,
                'password': obj.password
            },
            headers: {
                'Accept':'application/json',
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
            }
        }).then(function(response){
            require('utils').dump(response);
        });
```

But it fails with following response

```
{
"contentType": null,
"headers": [
    {
        "name": "Content-Length",
        "value": "8008"
    },
    {
        "name": "Server",
        "value": "Jetty(8.1.8.v20121106)"
    }
],
"id": 2,
"redirectURL": null,
"stage": "end",
"status": 415,
"statusText": "Unsupported Media Type",
"time": "2015-02-17T10:34:16.952Z",
"url": <someURL>,
"data": null
```

Whereas the equivalent CURL command is successful

> curl -i someurl -X POST -H Content-Type:application/json --data '{"memberId": 1234567,"password":"password"}'.

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed using npm or brew on your machine. It will not work. You need to compile casperjs from the source code to make it work. I donot have reference but I also read this from one forum.

Comment: Thanks @hasan.This resolved my issue.i found this thread on casperJS site https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/196 which suggests the same thing.But,no explanation around it though

Comment: Got the explanation on this mysterious behavior.The latest casperjs release was on Nov 23, 2013. Which is probably the one we'll get when downloading through a package manager.

However, support for posting JSON objects was not available until Feb 20, 2014.